# testng.xml is not a valid file when running from Maven Test

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am getting the above error and test are never ran.  Please help.I cannot run the test cases

Comment: you should provide you xml file as it is not a valid file

Comment: Can you run the tests at all?

Answer (score -2):

Is your XML valid?
With XML copy editor for example

Comment: Please don't "answer" questions with requests form more information!